# How can I write a binary Stream object to a file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I think I've tried every wrong way, and those few that don't just give ugly error messages write a garbled file that cannot be opened (you can still see the JFIF in it, but the jpeg magic smoke has been lost).

The Stream itself is  $contactInfo.Get_Item("Photo"). I think I need to do something like this:

```
$br = new-object System.IO.BinaryReader $contactInfo.Get_Item("Photo")
```

But past that, I don't know what to do. I've tried Googling, but I'm not even sure what I'm looking for to be quite honest.

The type of the Stream object is Microsoft.Lync.Model.UCStream.

Comment: What is the type that Get_Item() returns? Execute `$contactInfo.Get_Item("Photo").GetType().Fullname`.  If it is a byte[] then just do this `Set-Content photo.jpeg $contactInfo.Get_Item("Photo") -Encoding Byte`.

Comment: @KeithHill I've edited to include that information.

Comment: Use the Read() method to read until end of stream (-1). Take each int except the last and put it in a PowerShell byte[]. Then use `$bytes | Set-Content photo.jpeg -enc byte`.

Comment: @KeithHill Would you mind writing it as an answer with a short snippet?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to this particular type (UCStream) but in general you would write this in PowerShell like so:

```
$br = new-object io.binaryreader $contactInfo.Get_Item("Photo")
$al = new-object collections.generic.list[byte]
while (($i = $br.Read()) != -1)
{
    $al.Add($i)
}

Set-Content photo.jpeg $al.ToArray() -enc byte
```